# How to undo an improper purge?

Tags: installation, apt

As the title says, I did

`sudo apt-get purge mysql*`

and as a result, all packages with mysql in their name were purged. I tried a

`sudo apt-get install mysql*`

But, it also selected packages that weren't installed, and have broken dependencies.

Is there another way, other than copy-pasting each of the unselected package?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are trying to install the mysql server, please run "sudo apt-get install mysql-server" and update your question with the output from the command.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/547918/

Comment: From your pastebin output it installed without any errors :)

Comment: ok, thanks a lot! I hope that installed all the other libraries that were removed. that was a production server i messed with :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you are trying to install mysql, when you do `apt-get install mysql*` it tries to install 50 or so different packages and programs, some of which can not be installed together and some which can not be installed without other dependencies. Often these are specialist programs.

To install, just simply run:

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`