# Undo "apt-get purge" for google chrome

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome

I had some sort of browser-junk malware in my google chrome installation, so I wanted to completely destroy that installation. I followed the instructions here:

[How do I completely uninstall Google Chrome and Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82186/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-google-chrome-and-chromium)

So I used sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable (and deleted ~/.config/google-chrome). Now I want to reinstall, so I tried sudo apt-get install google-chrome stable, and it spit out this result:

```
$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package google-chrome-stable
```

It seems like ([How to undo an improper purge?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18987/how-to-undo-an-improper-purge)) suggests that should work, and sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ([Undo apt-get remove --purge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522712/undo-apt-get-remove-purge)) seems like overkill. Is there something simple I can do to reinstall this package?

Comment: Chrome is not in the default repos, when you uninstalled it, did it take out the Chrome repo too? Download it from Google and install the .deb.

Comment: Either that or use chromium

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a Chrome offline installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/104043/how-do-i-do-a-chrome-offline-installation)

Comment: Chrome adds its own PPA when you install the DEB, IIRC. If you purge it, it'll remove that PPA. You need to reinstall from a DEB.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments! I edited the question because it turns out it was quite specific to google chrome, and I compiled these comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome is not a default Ubuntu repository. Because of this, "apt-get purge" discarded the PPA (which was added automatically by google's .deb installer) from the repositories being managed by apt-get, and there is no way to simply apt-get install the repository again without re-adding the PPA.

The solution is to reinstall chrome from the .deb file, as described here: [How do I do a Chrome offline installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104043/how-do-i-do-a-chrome-offline-installation)